# Moving default controller CRUD methods to service class. Issues with creating response messages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a simple Web API controller to manage a Company entity. I'm trying to move all logic away from the controller by moving it into a service class (which in turns calls the repo) using Ninject to manage depedencies. All was going fine untill I needed to return an HttpResponseMessage object on the Delete action. I keep getting an error on the Request object "Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Request'"

How can I work with (or get the context?) of the Request object in a file that is not the controller?

CompanyController.cs

```
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
    private ICompanyService _companyService;

    public CompanyController(ICompanyService companyService)
    {
        _companyService = companyService;
    }

     // DELETE api/CompTest/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteCompany(int id)
    {
        return _companyService.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

CompanyService.cs

```
 public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
  {
    public readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork ;
    private readonly ICompanyRepository _companyRepository;

    public CompanyService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        var company = _companyRepository.GetCompanyById(id);

        if (company == null)
        {
          //ERROR HERE
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        _companyRepository.Delete(company);

        try
        {
            _companyRepository.Save();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            //ERROR HERE
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        //ERROR HERE
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, company);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inject the Request to your Service class.

Comment: Actually, I'm starting to wonder if this is the wrong approach. If I were to strait up pass in the current Request, I think that would break Dependency Inversion priciples...

No other class or process would be able to use the service.

Comment: Then maybe it is better to return generic / custom response, and handle it in client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `Request`object outside of your controller( ie. in a service class), you could use HttpContextBase class.

```
public class CompanyService: ICompanyService
{
   private readonly HttpContextBase _context;

   public CompanyService(HttpContextBase context)
   {
      _context = context;      
   }

   public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
   {
       _context.Request ....
   }
}
```

Ninject automatically resolves this HttpContextBase dependency with a HttpContextWrapper object. With ninject should only add CompanyService binding.

Comment: Now, what if I had another non-controller class or orchestration call CompanyService.Delete? Because sometimes I might want to delete an account as a side effect of some other action.

Comment: @Kronprinz Injecting presentation layer objects(request object in your case) in your domain services is not a good idea. You should rethink your approach. However, there can be services only accessed by your presentation layer (maybe cookie management, localization related services). Then you can use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Kronprinz, your Service belongs to another layer - it shouldn't know anything about HttpRequests/Responses. It might be reused in, for example, a WinForm / WPF or Web application. If it can't perform an operation, let it throw an exception and handle it in your controller which in turn will create an appropriate HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: Yes, I'm coming to that realization. See my reply to boran's answer :)